# Big titles don't work on <kbd> tag

Tags: bug

As we all know from unformatted config files, the `#` can make

## Very

### Big

#### Titles

*Unfortunately,* there where it matters as in making the following more readable:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and then <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1068684/344926) it just blows up the text and leaves the down-arrow inside the `<kbd>` just as small!

## <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and then <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Is this documented as "normal behaviour" somewhere because that would make it a "feature".  **>:-)**

### if not: **It's a bug!** :-)

Answer (score 8):

The purpose of the `#` element is **not** to create big, bold text but to mark the line as html-heading (see the editing help, section *Styling/Headers*)

- `#` is equivalent to `<h1>...</h1>`
- `##` is equivalent to `<h2>...</h2>`

So the behaviour you observe is neither a feature nor a bug.

Comment: HTML Heading = Big, Bold Title in my book (I knew this, but it should "embiggen" the <kbd> tags too IMHO...)

Comment: It shouldn't, because there is not much valid reason imo to use a keyboard shortcut in a heading. Headings are meant to break apart a post into smaller sections (e.g. very long tutorials or guides) or otherwise provide a logical named break - and not emphasis (this gets into accessibility issues for those with screen readers, but this is becoming an opinionated comment).